# How to put Dataframe into SQL where clause using Python?

Tags: sql, python-3.x

I have a Panda Dataframe df

Index   ID
0        '123',
1        '234',
2        '456',
3        '686',
4        '777'

I'd like to code in Python:

```
import pyodbc
conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",
                        user = "testuser",
                        passwd = "testpass",
                        db = "test")
Query = "select * from table1 where ID in ????????"
```

I'd like to make the '?' directly source my df, how should I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

After using `where` you should put a list, so as I understand you can replace ? with `df.values.reshape(-1,1)`
for this purpose, depend on your python version:

```
f"select * from table1 where ID in {df.values.reshape(-1,1)}"
```

or

```
'''select * from table1 where ID in {df.values.reshape(-1,1)}'''
```